# Mongodb $and not working properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I try to find data using mongodb $and in my nodejs app but it not working properly .

my code -

```
        var brand = req.param('Brand').split(',');
        brand = '"' + brand.join('","') + '"';
        if (query != '')
            query += ','
        query +=  '{"pro.brand": {$in:['+ brand  +']}}'

   itemdata.find({$and:[query]}, function(err, product) {
        if (err) {                
            return res.send({info: "Opps sorry"});
        }
        else {                
            res.json({deals: product}); 
        }  
    });
```

When i manually put query ( {"pro.brand": {$in:["Micromax"]}} ) then it work. Otherwise it not working (it return all data).

Comment: `$and` uses in aggregation. you have to do the following: `itemdata.find(query, function(err, product) {})`  but query should be object not string.

Comment: i try this but still not working

Comment: Could you post full query or function, I'll try to fix and send you back?

Answer (score 1):

The find, or the execution of this function must be an object. Here,

```
var brand = req.param('Brand').split(','); // Is Array
itemdata.find({
    $and:[
        "pro.band" : {
            $in : brand // Go into the object
        }
    ]
}, function(err, product) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send({info: "Opps sorry"});
    }
    else {                
        res.json({deals: product}); 
    }
});
```

Everything must be an object, and objects in javascript and JSON, have the same script. There is no need to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var brand = req.param('Brand').split(','); // Is Array
itemdata.find({

        "pro.band" : {
            $in : brand // Go into the object
        }

}, function(err, product) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send({info: "Opps sorry"});
    }
    else {                
        res.json({deals: product}); 
    }
});
```

by default it is and operator